# Método unescape no javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou com dúvidas no `script` abaixo:

```
function getURLParam(name) {
   var regex = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";

//mais código
   return unescape(results[1]);
```

Sou novata em `javascript`, não consigo entender o que é isso:

```
return unescape(results[1]);
```

- **O que essa parte faz ?**
- **Por que precisou utilizar isso ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unescape` é um método deprecado, mas a função dele é transformar caracteres em formato hexadecimal em caracteres "normais". Por exemplo

```
unescape("%E4%F6%FC");  // dá "äöü"
```

A parte `return` presumo que saibas, é o que indica à função que deve retornar o valor que vem a seguir.

A parte `results[1]` e `var regex = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";` dá-me ideia que tens um `.match` algures e então o `[1]` é o segundo elemento/resultado de um `match` que é precisamente o valor encontrado. Porque o `.match` tem no primeiro elemento da array que retorna a string completa e no segundo (e restantes) o resultado propriamente dito.

Comment: Então que dizer que ele vai pegar o segundo elemento do array? mas eu não sei o que ele irá fazer com esse retorno...

Comment: @gonz eu também não sei pois não faço ideia de que código tens :) Se colocares isso na pergunta posso talvez ajudar mais. O nome da função `getURLParam` dá uma dica. Tens alguma ideia porque essa função existe no teu código?

Comment: Ela pega dados da url, como exemplo: `?text=impressao&port=LPT1`. E essa função javascript envia para a applet java para tratar os dados recebidos.

Comment: @gonz já descobriste o que procuravas? Por exemplo nesse exemplo que colocaste, fazendo `var porta = getURLParam('port');` essa variável `porta` vai receber o valor `LPT1`.